# Codeigniter - controllers in subfolder, remove index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, pretty-urls

How can I remove 'index.php' from urls, if I have some controllers in the controllers folder and one in subfolder?
For example my frontend url looks like this : **domain.com/site/contact.html**
I would like my backend url look like this: **domain.com/system/settings/profile.html**, where system is not a controller, only a subfolder in the controllers folder.
When I type **domain.com/index.php/system/settings/profile.html**, everything works fine, it just does not look right.
Here's what's in my routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['system'] = "system/login";
$route['404_override'] = 'errors/error_404';
```

Here's what's in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1    !^(index\.php|img|css|public|tmp|download|javascript|rte|document|xajax_js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To remove index.php from URL first check mod_rewrite is enabled in apache after that add  this in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

in the .htaccess file and move the .htaccess file near to index.php location

```
/var/www/CodeIgniter/index.php
/var/www/CodeIgniter/.htaccess
```

in config.php in config folder set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

for removing index.php

create a .htaccess file in your root folder of project and write this much of code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

and save it.

remove the index.php from your URl and enjoy.
please note that.htacess doesn't run on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set `RewriteBase` like `RewriteBase /` or `RewriteBase /site/`

Comment: This is not working either. I'll need some kind of exception in the .htaccess file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a reserved controller name in routes.php file:

```
$route['system'] = "system/login";
```

You cannot name your subfolder 'system', because there is a folder 'system' in the root folder.